# Failed to open file composer.json. Please verify the archive

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

This is my **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "edgepay/payments",
    "description": "Add a payment method in Magento 2.",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "rmccue/requests": "v1.7.0",
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Edgepay\\Payments\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**I have issue to submitting my module. please check screenshot**

*Please Helps me to solve this error.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your module and composer files are placed in root location of your archive file & refer here - https://magento2tutorial.magestore.com/create-composer-json-file-to-upload-magento-2-extension-to-marketplace/
`Let's say you have developped a module under app/code/Vendor/Module, here is the procedure you have to follow:`

Create a composer file
Go to app/code/Vendor/Module and create the following composer.json file:

{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "Description of your Magento 2 module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Firstname Lastname",
      "email": "email@address.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.store.com/",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\Module\": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: No Same error .. can i contact you plz tonmoy.shome@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure. check your module name "name": "vendor/module",
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "0.1.0",
and other code syntax error.

This message means. Your Composer.json file path is not correct.

Correct File Path>>
vendor.zip>module>composer.json and OTHER_CODE_FILE

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you,

Please try this. ->Composer.json file path>>> module>composer.json No need app/code/vendor

Hope this helps you.